# Wordpress Genesis framework menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, genesis

There is something really strange happening with the menu on the child theme "Education" of the Genesis framework. This framework has two navigation positions: primary and secondary. As you can see [here](http://italianski-elleon.eu/bg/) both appear one under the other in the red area. However, there is a third position that seems to be hardcoded in the child theme (?) and won't go away even if I don't assign a position to the menu.

Can you guys give me an idea what is going on? I'm not very good at this stuff. I tried looking into the child theme's code, but found nothing referencing this...

Ultumately what I want to do is use the top position (the one in the white area), but I can't, because I need to make the site multilingual, but that top position doesn't appear in the menu options, so I can't assign different menus for the different languages.

Answer (score 0):

The white area at the top right is a widget area. The site already has two widgets in that Header Right widget area - a text widget (with the phone number), and a nav menu widget (the three locales).

You could make it two nav menu widgets. See Appearance -> Widgets, or use the Customizer. Alternatively, you could adjust the CSS, so that the red / grey locale 'tabs' become different looking links with a white background.

Also useful, if you do just need a single menu location there, would be the [Genesis Header Nav](https://github.com/garyjones/genesis-header-nav) plugin.